# How do I enable the console?

Tags: torchlight-2

I have read that there is a developer console in Torchlight II, but can't find how to enable it - there doesn't appear to be a keybind for it that I can see in the game options.

Is this something that needs to be enabled with a command line parameter before I launch the game?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**How to Activate the Console Window**

- Alter the file “**settings.txt**” found in your Torchlight 2 Save file.
- The save file is found here: **`%userprofile%\My Documents\My Games\Runic Games\Torchlight 2\save`** (There's a subfolder in there which is just a bunch of numbers, and in that subfolder is your settings.txt file, along with all of your saved games)
- Open the file with a text editor, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and search for `Console :0`. **Change the parameter from `Console :0` to `Console :1`** to activate the Developer Console, enabling use of cheat console commands in Torchlight 2.
- Now that console is activated, you can open the Console window while in-game by pressing <kbd>Insert</kbd>.

**NOTE** : Using the DEV CONSOLE risks having your account marked as suspicious to unmodified players of Torchlight 2 online. Use console commands at your own risk.

**Source:** [GameFront](http://www.gamefront.com/torchlight-2-dev-console-commands/)