# Is it possible to respec all skill points?

Tags: torchlight-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to respec?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85257/is-there-any-way-to-respec)

In town, there is an NPC that lets me respec the last 3 skills I chose, but I want to respec everything.  Is there a way to reset my skill points and start over?

Comment: Whoa, I didn't know it only did the last three! I would have paid a lot more attention to where I was putting my skill points if I knew that :(

Comment: I know it may not seem like it at first glance, but the comments finish up the answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are 2 possibilities as far as i know.

**Use the console:**

Bring up the console and type `RESETSKILLS` to reset all your skills. 
Remember however, this *may* flag your account as suspicious in Multiplayer!

[How to enable the console in Torchlight II](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85552/how-do-i-enable-the-console)
[Overview of all the commands in Torchlight II](http://www.gamefront.com/torchlight-2-dev-console-commands/)

**Use a shared stash savefile:**

There's a shared stash savefile [here](http://forums.runicgames.com/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=35925), to get potions that let you reset skillpoints. This will not flag you as a cheater, but is a little different.

First, quit the game and turn off Steam Cloud.
Then, navigate to your Torchlight II save folder (typically: `C:\Users\Username\Documents\My Games\Runic Games\Torchlight 2\save\RandomNumbers`) and make a copy of (or just rename) the **sharedstash.bin** file.
Now extract the sharedstash.bin file of the above link in the save folder.
You can now launch the game again and in your `Shared Stash` there will be some potions. Using a potion resets all your skillpoints.
Finally, to get your original shared stash back (not necessary if it was empty at first), you quit the game again, remove the downloaded sharedstash.bin file and replace it with the original sharedstash file.

Comment: I don't want to be labeled a cheater. :(  I'll check out that mod. Thanks.

Comment: @KyleTrauberman Just make sure to backup any save files in case things go wrong, you don't want to overwrite things and then find out it doesn't work! (it worked fine for me but you never know)